How to reduce propagation delay and mitigate dual-step transition
I am working on a circuit intended to protect digital output pins from the external voltages of the system on which they are designed to be used. I have built the circuit and found some "strange" behavior. (I used "strange" because I know this is the actual response, but I want to understand why) Below is the circuit I am talking about:

Some things to clarify about this circuit: TRIGGER_VREF_+ and TRIGGER_VREF_— are buffered and power amplified to adjust the positive and negative rails of the output signal. I am not including those circuit sections because they are working correctly. Q1, in this case, could be any signal. VCC/2 is just that; VCC is divided into two by a voltage divider. Below is an image showing how VCC/2 is generated.

So the OpAmp is working as a comparator, it is being powered with +12V and -12V, so I expect the output to swing something like +10V and -10V, OUT1 should follow the input signal but with another Amplitude set by VREF+ and VREF-, I understand that there is a danger zone for the gate voltage where both NMOS and PMOS could be on, in this case, R3 and R4 limits the current that could flow in this short circuit case, and also limits the current that could be sourced/sinked to another device.

Above is an image I took from my scope; it can be seen that it is having some problems (Note that Q1 is the yellow trace and OUT1 is the blue trace; also note 10KHz frequency for Q1):
a) the propagation delay, this propagation delay I assume, is the result of the OpAmp Open-Loop Gain and also the propagation delay caused by the MOSFETs turning on/off
b) It does two steps in each transition, one from VREF+ to GND and then to VREF-. (I assume it is not gnd and simply that both MOSFETs are biased, and it is only the divider between R3 and R4 because, at low voltages, this does not occur.)
So, my question is, can I lower this propagation delay with passive components? (Maybe adding biasing resistors to the gates so they can charge/discharge faster)
Also, Can I change the dual stepping, or is it something this circuit will always have?
To clarify some things:

IC3 is LM324
There is no virtual ground; it is a symmetrical power supply, and VCC Ground is common to this symmetrical power supply.

Edit:
I edited this to confirm that the middle step is the midpoint between VREF+ and VREF- and not ground, so this middle step voltage can be changed by R3 and R4 proportion when both MOSFETs are on, the output is given by :
Out1 = VREF- + (VREF+ * (R4/(R3+R4))) 
This equation neglects both MOSFETs VDS since low currents are used.

See the new scope image below. I am assuming the first step in the transition is Q2 turning off, and the second step is Q1 turning on. I want to assume this is due to a slow transition from the opamp from -VSat to Vsat; the same happens on a falling edge. So, I assume this is mainly due to the opamp's low open-loop gain.


Please note that the propagation delay (green tags) is much longer than both MOSFETs transitions (pink tags); I still do not understand why.

Are you using a virtual ground? what are your supplies? the source impedance matters. What is the part number of IC3B?

No virtual ground is used. I'm using two regulated power supplies (12V each in series) to supply IC3. VCC comes from another regulated power supply currently set to 5V (Ground connected to the common of the other two supplies), and IC3 is LM324. I'm not sure if, with source impedance, you mean the signal being fed to the opamp as Q1. It is an Arbitrary Waveform Generator, but I do not expect it to matter that much because opamp inputs have such high input impedance

@ChecheRomo Few questions: What external events is this circuit supposed to protect against? Why use an opamp when a comparator is designed for switching - opamps aren't designed for operating open-loop (no negative feedback). The 10k resistors will protect the MOSFETs from shoot-through, but now your output impendence is weak. Will that be a problem?

@MOSFET It should protect against shorting to any voltage between +12V and -12V. Output impedance shouldn't be a problem; all the devices in this system should have high input impedance, around at least 100k ohms, but most inputs are buffered, so I don't think it could be a problem. Lastly, I used the opamps instead of comparators because I had many stocked in my shop. Do you think this could be the source of some problems? I do not know the difference between using an opamp as a comparator and using a dedicated comparator IC.

What are the rails at for IC3B?

@VoltageSpike Opamp rails are at +12V and -12V

The LM324 is what makes this circuit so slow. In particular, its datasheet lists a slew rate of typically 0.5V/µs. Given that its output has to swing approximately from -10V to +10V, which is a span of 20V, I'd expect it to take 40µs to switch.  Your scope shot shows 30µs, which is close enough. This also explains the intermediate output voltage: As the OpAmp slowly slews its output voltage, it first turns on both FETs for an extended period of time, until it finally slews far enough to turn the other FET off.
OpAmps are designed to do this - their internal compensation networks intentionally limit the slew rate of their outputs to make them stable with feedback. If you measure the OpAmp's output voltage in your circuit, you'll see a nice linear ramp.
The fix is to use a comparator, not an OpAmp. Comparators lack this compensation circuitry because they're designed for speed, not for closed-loop stability.

I appreciate your answer, Jonathan. It seems I was not that far in my reasoning that the  Open-Loop Gain and your more reasonable assertion of the Slew Rate made this so slow. Also, I used the cheapest OpAmp in the market, so I should have expected the bandwidth to be that bad. I assume that by using a comparator, the middle step should also be mitigated, right?

@ChecheRomo You can never get rid of this middle step as long as the FET gates are connected to each other. You can, however, make the circuit so fast that its duration is short enough to not matter. Just try it with a proper comparator and see if that's good enough.

I see; I think I now better understand what is happening on the circuit. I guess this circuit is ok for low-frequency applications ( >10KHz ); if I wanted to increase the bandwidth of the device, a comparator with a lower propagation delay would be ideal. The thing would be to find a comparator capable of handling dual supply for it to switch both MOSFETs because the comparator output should swing from at least -10V to 10V (VREF+ is 0V to 12V, and VREF- is -12V to 0V); thanks again, Jonathan, for your helpful insight.

@ChecheRomo The good old LM2901B should get you to around 1µs. All it needs is a pull-up resistor on its output; 4.7k should work well.

Thanks! I'll give it a go with LM2901B

You should consider doing it this way:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I believe the issue you are seeing is from the opamp being used as a comparator. They aren't designed to switch fast and also, weird behaviors are observed when the inputs are far apart or near the rails. Phase-reversal is common on some structures. I would recommend using a rail-to-rail output opamp if you need the output to span the power rails. May not be required for your app.
The MOSFET's don't add any value other than inverting the signal. So I removed them from your original design. If you need a non-inverted signal, the treatment will be different.
R1 could still be 10k, however, with a load impendence of 100k, you will be down around 9% of your signal. That may be acceptable. I used 2.2k for R1 because it is sufficient to protect U1 from shorts - worst-case: 24V back feeding the comparator will require a comparator that can source/sink 11mA.
R4 is optional. But a high value here will provide some noise immunity.

I like the Hysteresis implementation with a comparator. The only thing I would change to the diagram you took the time to make is that R2 and R3 should be connected to VCC and GND instead of VREF+ and VREF—because Q1 is intended to have an amplitude of VCC (imagine using an Arduino to generate the signals. VCC could be 5V or 3.3V, that's why I had that voltage divider about VCC). I'll also try this implementation; I always thought hysteresis would be a nice addition to this circuit, so kudos for showing this implementation with way fewer components.

I drafted this based on memorizing your circuit for 6 seconds. So trivial mistakes are subject to occurrence. 95% of the time the divider is made across the rails. I'll update the circuit. BTW, You should use a totem pole output comparator. Not open-collector outputs.
